# Riddle Me Riddle This

Tags: riddle

> I have arms but they cannot move,
>
> I breathe what you cannot,
>
> The strongest man cannot break me,
>
> But he and others break parts of me,

What am I?

Comment: Remember to accept if it is correct! :D

Answer (score 26):

I would guess

> trees.

I have arms but they cannot move,

> branches of a tree

I breathe what you cannot,

> trees breathe carbon dioxide

The strongest man cannot break me,

> hard to uproot a tree, especially if there is a thick trunk

But he and others and break parts of me,

> leaves, branches, fruit, etc.

Comment: HNQ is a strange thing... I logged on and saw +120 rep and thought it was because I registered on a new site or something

Comment: Tree branches can move and one man could break even the strongest tree.

Comment: @SwiftPanda it seems to fit the riddle the best - would you not agree? (were you the downvoter?)

Comment: I agree it fits well but is not robust for all clues as I explicitly pointed out. If you're answer is accepted I will remove my downvote and move it to the riddle. 1/17 votes being down is nothing to sweat or retaliate over.

Comment: @SwiftPanda was just wondering why, don't really care about the downvote. it's your opinion, after all.

Answer (score 5):

> The milky way

I have arms but they cannot move,

> The milky way's spirals are referred to as arms

I breathe what you cannot,

> Most of the galaxay is a vacuum, we can not breath

The strongest man cannot break me,

> You can not independently break the whole galaxy

But he and others break parts of me,

> Anyone who breaks anything is breaking a part of the milky way

Comment: I would believe the object of your answer does not “breathe“

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> Tank?

I have arms but they cannot move,

> A tank has arms (fire-arms) a.k.a weapons.

I breathe what you cannot,

> Breathe gasoline?

The strongest man cannot break me,

> No one man can break a tank

But he and others break parts of me,

> A guys can use a weapon (bazooka?) to punch a hole in it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one of my longshots. Are you

> An Airplane?

I have arms but they cannot move

> Airplane wings looks like the arms, yet they don't move.

I breathe what you cannot

> Due to the high altitude of where the plane can fly, maybe?

The strongest man cannot break me

> One man alone won't be able to break a whole airplane.

But he and others break parts of me

> More than 1 person grouped can basically break it into parts..

Comment: No, but the last one isn't very specific the last part.

Answer (score 3):

> Neurons in the brain

I have arms but they cannot move,

> Neurons never move it's axons or dendrites, they need to grow new ones every time to make new synapsis

I breathe what you cannot,

> Information. We need air to remain alive, and although we could resist some time without it, in the end we would just die. When neurons are not stimulated with new information enough throughout their lives, they got not much else to do other than just die off. As explained in goo.gl/yByQva

The strongest man cannot break me,

> In a game of chess for example, you can be the strongest man out there, but if you don't know playing chess, you don't beat your opponent, or "break" their intelligence (neurons(synapsis))

But he and others break parts of me,

> The allegory of the cave, or Plato's cave, shows as an example of how what's commonly accepted by everyone as the truth, might not be it. So a group of people may not reason your sayings, and they may condemm you (call you crazy), depriving you from thinking too much, thus hurting your neurons, which won't get much stimulated anymore

Comment: No, its not really close, but, ya its not correct try again.